# Why does bidi text render differently in Chrome/FF compared to IE, and which is the correct behavior?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, html-rendering, bidi

Here is a very simple snippet of HTML to display the issue:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:100px;direction:rtl;">(One) Two</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome and Firefox, the result is "One) Two)" while in IE the result is "(One) Two". As far as I can tell from my initial research of bidi text, the difference is that Chome and FF let the "neutral" character (the punctuation) that is not surrounded on both sides by LTR text inherit the parent's direction, which is RTL. IE seems to notice that the text only includes LTR characters and neutral characters so it makes the punctuation LTR. Does anyone know which behavior is correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone runs into this same issue, I have found a little bit of clarity. In this case, IE is correct. [Here](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=302469) is the bug filed for Chrome. The BiDi algorithm was apparently updated a couple of years ago and it included making brackets match each other.

Comment: Do you know if there's any easy workaround for this?